# Quoting mathreviews

Tags: mathematical-writing

I would like to credit a reviewer who made a very nice corollary to the paper he was reviewing. Is there any more or less common standard of quoting MathReviews? I would be most grateful for an example of how to do it.

Comment: One possible solution would be as follows: If the proof is short, you can repeat the proof and add a sentence like "I learned this proof from the review of the paper X appeared in Mathematical Review MR:number", by "the name of the reviewer". I suppose you don't need to cite it like a journal paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question seems trivial. Since everyone uses electronic version nowadays,
why don't you write just
Author, Review of, MR number.
If the journal editor will want to edit this, let her edit.
I quoted a Zentralblatt review once like this:
[53] H. Schmidt, Zentralblatt fur Math. 27 (1943), 309-311.
(This was in pre-computer era).

Comment: It is a good student question.  Not research mathematics.